# Calculate z score by using previous row value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
 ids    value   
  1      0.1
  1      0.2
  1      0.14   
  2      0.22
    ....
```

I am trying to loop through each ids and calculate a new column 'z-score' for each id.

```
for id, row in df.groupby('ids'):
    row.reset_index(inplace=True)
    row.loc[0, 'z_score'] = 0
    row.loc[1, 'z_score'] = 0

    for i in range (2, len(row)):
        row.loc[i, 'z_score'] = (row.loc[i, value] - row.loc[0:i-1][value].mean()) / row.loc[0:i-1][value].std()
    print(row)
    # How to add each "row" back to the original dataframe?
```

The first two should have z score of 0.  Then use the previous values (up to i-1) to calculate the mean and standard deviation for each iteration of z score. My df will look like this:

```
 ids    value    z_score    
  1      0.1       ..              
  1      0.2       ..            
  1      0.14      ..          
  2      0.22      ..            
     ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scipy.stats.zscore`:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore

df['zscore'] =  df.groupby('ids')['value'].transform(zscore)
print(df)
   ids  value    zscore
0    1   0.10 -1.135550
1    1   0.20  1.297771
2    1   0.14 -0.162221
3    2   0.22       NaN
```

Or, sticking to pandas,

```
df['zscore'] = df.groupby('ids').value.apply(
                    lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std(ddof=0))
print(df)
       ids  value    zscore
    0    1   0.10 -1.135550
    1    1   0.20  1.297771
    2    1   0.14 -0.162221
    3    2   0.22       NaN
```

---

If you want an expanding zscore, try `groupby` + `expanding`:

```
g = df.groupby('ids').value.expanding(min_periods=1)
df['zscore'] = (df['value'] - g.mean().values) / g.std(ddof=0).values

print(df)
   ids  value    zscore
0    1   0.10       NaN
1    1   0.20  1.000000
2    1   0.14 -0.162221
3    2   0.22       NaN
```

Comment: This doesn't change the mean & standard deviation as the index increase

Comment: @Matt-pow Sorry, I don't follow. This does what you want, does it not?

Comment: @Matt-pow Okay, do you want an expanding zscore per group? Will you see my edit please?

Comment: the mean and standard deviation should be based on the previous rows within the same id. Instead of the mean / std of all the rows within the same id. @coldspeed

Comment: @Matt-pow I got it, just let me know if my edit is what you wanted, thanks.

Comment: Good to know about expanding. Thanks!

Comment: @coolspeed Does df['value'] going through all the values? I just want to go over values for each id.

Comment: @Matt-pow Yeah, hence the line above. `groupby` and `expanding` are for the mean and standard deviation, which I need to compute the (vectorised) zscore. Just do a little back-of-the-envelope calculation and you'll be able to figure out whether the math checks out yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183396/discussion-between-matt-pow-and-coldspeed).